# Angular 2 click event causing entire component to re-initialize (losing state)

Tags: angular, events, recursion, tree

I'm attempting to build a simple tree-like-structure that allows data to be nested so that you can expand/collapse children of nodes and ultimately make a selection by clicking on an element.

The problem I'm having is that when I fire the click event to toggle showing/hiding of child nodes, the top-level component is being re-initialized and it resets the flag back to false and therefore doesn't show the child nodes.

Here is all the relevant code involved:

lookup-data.interface.ts:

```
export interface LookupData {
     id: string;
     label: string;
     parentId?: string;
}
```

lookup-modal.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { LookupData } from './lookup-data.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'lookup-modal',
    host: {
        '(window:keydown)': 'handleKeyPress($event)'
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/shared/lookup-modal/lookup-modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/assets/css/modal.css']
})
export class LookupModalComponent {
    constructor() { }

    @Input() label: string = '';
    @Input() data: LookupData[] = [];
    @Output() close: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    search: string = '';

    get topLevelData(): LookupData[] {
        return this.data.filter((item: LookupData): boolean => !item.parentId);
    }

    handleKeyPress(event: any): void {
        if (event && event.keyCode === 27) {
            this.close.emit();
        }
    }
}
```

lookup-modal.component.html:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in fsi-modal-backdrop"></div>
<div tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog"
     class="modal fade scale up in fsi-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg fsi-modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content fsi-modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header fsi-modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close.emit()">
                    <span>×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{label}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body nopad fsi-modal-body">  
                <input type="search" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="search" />

                <div style="margin-top: .5rem;">
                    <div *ngFor="let topLevelItem of topLevelData; let i = index;">
                        <lookup-item [item]="topLevelItem"
                                     [data]="data"
                                     [i]="i"
                                     [search]="search"
                                     (selection)="close.emit($event)"></lookup-item>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer fsi-modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger pull-left" type="button" (click)="close.emit('')">Clear</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="close.emit()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

lookup-item.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { LookupData } from './lookup-data.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'lookup-item',
    templateUrl: '/app/shared/lookup-modal/lookup-item.component.html'
})
export class LookupItemComponent {
    constructor() { }
    @Input() item: LookupData;
    @Input() i: number;
    @Input() data: LookupData[] = [];
    @Input() search: string = '';
    @Output() selection: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    showChildren: boolean = false;

    // temp/test, not needed
    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.item.id === '1') 
            console.log(this.item.label);
    }

    toggleChildren(): void {
        console.log('toggle');
        this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
    }

    get children(): LookupData[] {
        return this.data.filter((i: LookupData): boolean => i.parentId === this.item.id);
    }
}
```

lookup-item.component.html:

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 5px;"
     [ngStyle]="{'border-top': i || item.parentId ? 'none' : '1px solid #eee', 'border-bottom': item.parentId ? 'none' : '1px solid #eee'}">

    <div class="col-xs-1" 
         *ngIf="children.length" 
         style="cursor: pointer; text-align: center;"
         (click)="toggleChildren()">

        <span class="glyphicon"
              [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-triangle-right': !showChildren, 'glyphicon-triangle-down': showChildren}"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-11"
         [ngClass]="{'col-xs-offset-1': !children.length}"
         (click)="selection.emit(item.id)"
         style="cursor: pointer;">

        {{item.label}}

        <div *ngIf="showChildren">
            <div *ngFor="let child of children; let j = index;">
                <lookup-item [item]="child"
                             [data]="data"
                             [i]="j"
                             [search]="search"
                             (selection)="selection.emit($event)"></lookup-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my problem is, when the (click) event is fired and calls toggleChildren() in the lookup-item component, for some reason the ngOnInit() method gets run again (the whole component re-initializes itself). This causes the showChildren attribute get reset to false even though the toggleChildren() method should be setting it to true, and therefor the child nodes never get shown.

I have spent hours on this issue already and have tried researching but have found nothing relevant to my issue anywhere on the internet as of yet.

I'm really hoping someone can point out a glaring error I've missed because I'm quite stumped at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using arrow function `toggleChildren = () => { //code }`?

Comment: I don't think defining it as anonymous arrow function will help in this case. toggleChildren is just a method on the LookupItemComponent class that should get executed when the div containing the arrow glyphicon gets clicked. It does get called, but for some reason the component is also being reinitialized so it's wiping out the state changes that happen in the method call. I've never seen anything like this happen before.

Comment: The arrow function will retain the context of your component so it may help. Did you see any error in the console?

Comment: I gave it a try - no dice, unfortunately. And nope, no console errors. It just prints out the console.logs showing that the toggleChildren method indeed gets called then the ngOnInit method immediately after - I also added checks to show that when toggleChildren is called, showChildren does get set to true, then in the ngOnInit it shows as false again.

Comment: I've also tried removing the recursion to see if that was causing it (commented out where <lookup-item> is referenced inside of itself. The problem still happens even without that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I just figured this out - it had to do with the way I was generating the input data (which isn't shown in the original question because I didn't think it was relevant at first) - instead of passing an actual array into it I was using a typescript getter and it was forcing it to re-initialize when I tried to make changes to the data for some reason.